# Entity Framework Required Property Without Relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Given

```
class Foo()
{
    Guid FooId;
    Bar Bar;
}

class Bar()
{
    Guid BarId;
}
```

`Bar` is a required property of `Foo` but there is no database relationship between `Foo` and `Bar`. Having assigned a `Foo` to a `Bar` it is OK to delete that `Bar` from the database without deleting any `Foo`.

How is this configured in the fluent API? If I try

```
entity.Property(e => e.Bar)
    .IsRequired();
```

Entity Framework migrations throws the error

```
The property 'Bar' cannot be added to the entity type 'Foo' because a navigation property with the same name already exists on entity type 'Foo'
```

If I try `entity.HasOne(e => e.Bar).WithMany().IsRequired();` Entity Framework creates a relationship in the database between `Foo` and `Bar`.

How do I make `Bar` a required property of `Foo` without creating a relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option one**

```
class Foo()
{
    Guid FooId;
    Guid BarId;
}
```

No object reference - no relationship. Guid is required by default, no additional configuration is needed. You may put any value here, even if no `Bar` records with this BarId exists.

**Option two**

Other way for you is to create/have the relationship, with enforcing referential integrity, but with cascade option `SetNull`:

```
fooEntity.HasOne(x => x.Bar).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

This (you should check is you DB provider/engine support this) will not delete `Foo` when you delete `Bar` it is linked to. Instead, `Foo.BarId` will be set to `null`. Of course, this will cause `BarId` field in `Foo` table to have nullable column type.

Comment: So @Dmitry if we want to be able to navigate using `Foo.Bar` we have to have a relationship?

Comment: Yep. Either you have relationship in DB (and EF knows about it and helps you), or you have no relationship and navigate between objects (and "enforce" any "integrity") "manually".

Comment: One more note. There is `DeleteBehavior.SetNull` action - if it's OK for your app to set `Foo.BarId` to null when record from `Bar` is deleted - you can create relationship with this behavior value.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry. `DeleteBehavior.SetNull` sounds more like we are looking for. If you could demonstrate that I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with second option.